# can't sign out firebase user

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign out currently signed in user in my angular app. That's my client service:

```
  export class AuthClientService {
      public register(email: string, password: string): Observable<Object> {
        return from(
          createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.firebaseService.auth, email, password)
        );
      }
    
      public logIn(email: string, password: string): Observable<Object> {
        return from(
          signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.firebaseService.auth, email, password)
        );
      }
    
      public logOut(): Observable<void> {
        return from(signOut(this.firebaseService.auth));
      }
    constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}
   }
```

and firebase service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirebaseService {
  public app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  public auth = getAuth();
}
```

but when i call logOut function theres this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to
> read only property 'currentUser' of object '[object Object]'
> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'currentUser' of object '[object Object]'
> at index-8593558d.js:2473
> at Generator.next ()
> at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
> at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
> at asyncToGenerator.js:32
> at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1387)
> at asyncToGenerator.js:21
> at AuthImpl.directlySetCurrentUser (index-8593558d.js:2466)
> at index-8593558d.js:2329
> at Generator.next ()
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
> at zone.js:1120
> at zone.js:1136
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372)
> at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28692)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371)
> at Zone.run (zone.js:134)
> at zone.js:1276
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28679)

app is calling it from ngrx effects, but i don't think thats an issue, because i tried to call it without ngrx and there's still this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some investigation i found solution, i am not sure about the cause of this problem, but this may be helpful to someone. First i moved user auth logic from ngrx effects to Angular fire auth observer like this:

```
  public authObserver(): void {
    this.angularFireAuth.user.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.store.dispatch(readCredentials({ userCredential: user }));
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }
    });
  }
```

After that i realized that cause of error was passing user object to ngrx action function. When i create deep copy of the object user and pass it to function like this it works fine.

```
  public authObserver(): void {
    this.angularFireAuth.user.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
        this.store.dispatch(readCredentials({ userCredential: copy }));
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }
    });
  }
```